# Structure arrays with pointer

Tags: c

I'm learning C.I wrote code and error is "passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct humans{
    sname[20];
}human;


int main(){
    human *person=(human *)malloc(sizeof(human)*1);

    int i,k,z;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        person=(human *)realloc(person,sizeof(human)*(i+1));
        strcpy(*person[i].sname , "john");
    }


    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    printf("%s",*person[i].sname);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to use malloc/realloc.

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: You keep reallocating one row, but accessing beyond the rows allocated.  The new size is the new _total_ size, not the amount to be added.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler fixed(edited) and compiled but screen is empty

Comment: Person is already a pointer so you are trying to strcpy a pointer to a pointer. Try using strcpy(person[i].sname , "John"); and print printf("%s",person[i].sname);

Comment: @TJGreen thank you! its working :)

Answer (score 0):

Where you have `*person[i].sname`, you want `person[i].sname` instead. When you put `*` before it, you force the array to decay to a pointer to its first element which, when dereferenced, gives you the value of the first element.

Also:

```
    person=(human *)realloc(person,sizeof(human)*1);
```

This `1` should be `i + 1`.

Comment: i wrote person=(human *)realloc(person,sizeof(human)*(i+1)); and it compiled but screen is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the direct issues in your program.
The deeper point here though is how to get to the pointer you want.

`array[4]` gets the value of the 4th element.
`array` gets the pointer to the first element
`&array[4]` gets the pointer to the 4th element
`array + 4` gets the pointer to the 4th element
`*(array + 4)` gets the value of the 4th element
`*array[4]` gets the value, treats it as a pointer and tries to get a value from the pointers target - this would require extra fiddling to convince the compiler what type that would be. In most cases this is likely meaningless.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct humans {
    char sname[20];
}human;


void MyStrCpy(char * dst, int dst_n, char * src, int src_n)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < dst_n && n < src_n; ++n)
    {
        dst[n] = src[n];
        if (src[n] == 0) break;
    }
    dst[dst_n] = 0;
}


int main() {
    human *person = (human *)malloc(sizeof(human) * 1);

    int i, k, z;
    for (i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        person = (human *)realloc(person, sizeof(human)*(i + 1));
        //I replace strcpy so it compiles on my machine
        MyStrCpy(person[i].sname, 20, "john", 5);
        person[i].sname[20] = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", person[i].sname);
    }
    return 0;
}
```